# Is there use of the numbers of Stirling and of Bell for a combinatorial exercise?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients

Let be $\mathcal F=\{A,B,C\}$ a partition of a set $X$, with $|A|=|B|=4$ and $|C|=2$  where $\mathcal R_{\mathcal F}$ is a relation of equivalence. How many elements contains the relation of equivalence $\mathcal R_{\mathcal F}$ associated with remembering that the elements of the relation $\mathcal R_{\mathcal F}$ are ordered pairs?

---

Starting that I'm helping an universitary student. I have treated combinatorics in a very marginal way during my university period.

I have thinked that if I consider that $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$, the distinct equivalence relations on the set $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ are as many as the partitions of $A$. To count I should to built a table considering
that I have orderd pairs if I fix two elements (we have couples):

$$\binom{4}{2}=6$$

that is the number of ways to choose two of the four elements...after for me is very complicated...
Do exist a simple solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{F}}$ is the equivalence relation associated with the partition $\mathcal{F}$, its equivalence classes are the sets $A,B$, and $C$. For any $x,y\in A$, $\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{F}}$, even if $x=y$, and similar statements are true of $B$ and $C$. Thus, $\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{F}}$ consists of all of the ordered pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $x,y\in A$, or $x,y\in B$, or $x,y\in C$: $$\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{F}}=(A\times A)\cup(B\times B)\cup(C\times C)\,.$$

There are $|A|\cdot|A|=4^2=16$ ordered pairs in $A\times A$. Similarly, there are $16$ ordered pairs in $B\times B$, and there are $|C|\cdot|C|=2^2=4$ ordered pairs in $C\times C$, so

$$|\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{F}}|=16+16+4=36\,:$$

$\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{F}}$ has $36$ elements.

Comment: Thank you very much with a lot of my heart. But do you think that is it possibile to use the numbers of Stirling or of Bell in this case? I have not done at my university also this tipologies of exercise.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You’re very welcome. The Stirling and Bell numbers are not relevant here; I really don’t see any way to make use of them for this problem, which deals with much simpler ideas.

Comment: I'm very happy  to meet you (virtually). This student is from the Faculty of Economics and Finance and unfortunately beyond my limits of knowledge (exercises of this type I have never done) he also has difficulty in understanding a simple symbology. They do not study the theory and immediately perform the exercises with the pretense that I do them in two steps.